# How should I use an ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> for adding text data as well as images?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

How should I use an ArrayList> for adding text data as well as images?

```
//first activity
persons = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    persons.put("teacher_name", TEACHER_NAME);//TEACHER_NAME is JSON response
                    persons.put("course_name", COURSE_NAME);//COURSE_NAME JSON response
                    persons.put("subject_name", SUBJECT_NAME);//SUBJECT_NAME JSON response
                    persons.put("profileimage", PROFILE_IMAGE);//PROFILE_IMAGE JSON response
                    personList.add(persons); //personList is an arrayList
i.putExtra("teachersAL", personList); // Intent to another activity

//Second class

teachername = getIntent().getStringExtra("teacher_name");
                coursename = getIntent().getStringExtra("course_name");
                subjectname = getIntent().getStringExtra("subject_name");
                profileimage = getIntent().getStringExtra("profileimage");

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(//MainHome is Second class's name
                        MainHome.this, personList, R.layout.mainhome,
                        new String[]{teachername,coursename,subjectname,profileimage},
                        new int[]{R.id.teachername, R.id.coursename, R.id.subjectname, R.id.profileimage}
                );
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here I am receiving the URL of the image, but I want to add the image along with the other data to my Arraylist, so that I can pass it to the Views easily using a SimpleAdapter.

How can I achieve this?
Am I doing the right thing or should I opt for some other way?

Comment: You could encode you image into a Base64 `String`, for example. Or use `HashMap<String, Object>` instead.

Comment: try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564862/how-do-you-add-images-beside-text-in-an-arraylist-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564862/how-do-you-add-images-beside-text-in-an-arraylist-in-android) I think its help u

Comment: Thanks for replying guys! I will try these stuffs.

Comment: My concern is that I had stored the URL of the image on mysql table along with other data and I am retrieving it using JSON and then I am adding those responses to my hashmap and then hashmap to arraylist. So till here I haven't converted my URL to Bitmap. I am doing that on another activity. So how do I use the URL response on my arraylist and later convert it into an image and view it on my UI using SimpleAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your bitmap to Base64 string
Here is code for encoding:

You can user **Base64** class to do so,

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT); // Add this string to your HasMap.
```

But, you'll need bytearray though,

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

You can your Base64 using some other built in methods.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks mate! I am able to view all the data of a single user on my UI. So, if I am using select * I am getting only single user's data. I want to view multiple users data on my UI. So how do I do that! Please help me out!

Comment: You could use List<HashMap<String, String>> to store multiple user data.

Comment: I am exactly doin the same thing! But how do I insert an image onto that list/arraylist

Comment: In your code you are using Intent and all. Why is that??

Answer (score 0):

You can store the link of the image in the `HashMap` as:

```
list.add(new HashMap("imageUrl"," your image url"));
```

Converting the image into `ByteArray` and storing it as an image is not recommended as it takes a lot of memory and processing.

If the image is on some server you can use `Glide` or `Picasso` to easily load them into your app like:

```
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(yourImageView);
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(yourImageView);
```

Or if you have your images in your sd card then you can target a specific folder like:

```
File imgFile = new  File(imageUrl);

if(imgFile.exists()){
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Comment: I am using SimpleAdapter to insert the data directly into my layout. So if I am storing URL on my arraylist how can I display the data on my Android UI

Comment: Thanks mate! I am able to view all the data of a single user on my UI. So, if I am using select * I am getting only single user's data. I want to view multiple users data on my UI. So how do I do that! Please help me out!

Comment: you should post your code in the question or else it will be really hard to help you.

Comment: persons = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    persons.put("teacher_name", TEACHER_NAME);
                    persons.put("course_name", COURSE_NAME);
                    persons.put("subject_name", SUBJECT_NAME);
                    persons.put("profileimage", PROFILE_IMAGE);
                    personList.add(persons);

Comment: personList is an arraylist and TEACHER_NAME, COURSE_NAME, etc are the JSON responses.

Comment: So I am adding everything to my arraylist and passing arraylist to another activity.  i.putExtra("teachersAL", personList); ///where i is an intent

Comment: adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainHome.this, personList, R.layout.mainhome,
                        new String[]{teachername,coursename,subjectname,profileimage},
                        new int[]{R.id.teachername, R.id.coursename, R.id.subjectname, R.id.profileimage}
                );
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: using the adapter to pass the responses to appropriate layout elements

Comment: edit the question and post all the code.. hard to read in comments

Comment: My concern is profileimage contains a URL to my image, So how do I add the image to the arraylist and later pass it to an imageview